# Regular expression MatchCollection returns 1 instead of expected 3

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a long string in C# where it's formatted such as \\server\value
I've been using a regular expression pattern of "(?<='\\\\).*(?=\\)" to extract the server from the string.  However there's a use case where multiple '\server\value' strings could be chained together like so '\\serverA\value1' + '\\serverB\value2' + '\\serverC\value3'

I'm trying to use the MatchCollection to extract all the server name using the pattern (?<=.\\\\).*(>=\\)

the period in the first grouping construct to account for the ' character.  I would expect the result to return 3 occurences but it only returns 1.  What's wrong with my pattern?

```
   string expression = "'\\\\serverA\\value1' + '\\\\serverB\\value2' + '\\\\serverC\\value3'";
   string pattern = @"(?<=\\\\).*(?=\\)";

   MatchCollection matches;
   matches = Regex.Matches(expression, pattern);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got, I're getting result like this

```
serverA\value1' + '\\serverB\value2' + '\\serverC
```

And you want to get these matches:

```
serverA 
serverB 
serverC
```

You can use *lazy quantification*:

```
(?<=\\\\).*?(?=\\)
```

Comment: does the ? in .*? mean that it matches the previous element one or more times or does it mean matches the previous element zero or more times, but as few times as possible?

Comment: @user3421997, `?` marks previous quantifier as lazy. Actual quantifier will bring the same sense. And while `*` means "zero and more", `*?` means "zero and more".

Answer (score 1):

You can try next pattern:

```
@"\\\\(.*?)\\"
```